# Understanding fractional knapsack, arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers

Just started learning C programming and decided to take a class in algorithmic Toolbox on Coursera. One of the challenges is writing a code using fractional knapsack, maximizing the value of loot and a pseudo code was given to help in coding the solution. Below are the pseudo code and the code I wrote for the pseudo code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

int knapsack(int value[], int weight[])
{
    int capacity = 100;
    int val = 0;
    int array[] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 1; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        if (capacity == 0)
        {
            return val;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if (weight[i] > 0 && (value[i] / weight[i]))
            {
                int a = min(weight[i], capacity);
                val = val + a * (value[i] / weight[i]);
                weight[i] = weight[i] - a;
                array[i] = array[i] + a;
                capacity = capacity - a;
            }
        }
    }
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    int value[100];
    int weight[100];
    scanf("%d", &value[100]);
    scanf("%d", &weight[100]);
    printf("%d", knapsack(value[100], weight[100]));
    return 0;
}
```

pseudo code

```
Knapsack(W, w1,v1,......wn,vn)
A <-- [0,0,], V <-- 0;
repeat n times:
if W =  0:
return (V,A)
select i with Wi > 0 and max vi/wi
a <-- min(wi, W)
V <-- V + a(vi/wi)
wi <-- wi - a, A[i] <-- A[i] + a, W <-- W - a
return (V, A)
```

I am getting errors when I compile such as "passing argument 1 of 'knapsack' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"

```
printf("%d", knapsack(value[100],weight[100]));
```

"expected int * but argument is of type 'int'"

```
int knapsack(int value[], int weight[])
```

I also want to know if it is a good practice to declare `int value[], int weight[]` in the function `int knapsack` argument and also more explanation in using arrays and pointers in situations like this.

Comment: In `printf()` change `knapsack(value[100],weight[100])` to `knapsack(value,weight)`

Comment: I do not understand your last question about the "good practise". If the fucntion demands multiple values of same type, then one has to use an array, there is no other option

Comment: `int knapsack(int value[], int weight[])` ----> `int knapsack(size_t capacity, int value[capacity], int weight[capacity])`

Comment: Note that `value[i] / weight[i]` is integer division, in which fractional parts are truncated; this is perhaps not what you want.

Comment: @GAURANGV VYAS was thinking int value[ ] isn't correct but compiling but read it correct with the C99 standard.

Comment: @Codor so meaning it is better to declare array value and weight has float?

Answer (score 0):

```
int knapsack(int value[], int weight[])
```

The above statement gives the compiler the information about **HOW** the function should be called (type of arguments) and **WHAT** the function will return.

1. It says the function knapsack will return an integer value (the 1st int).
2. Its name is knapsack (case-sensitive).
3. It expects two arguments: an integer array (named value) and an integer array (named weight).

Points 1, 2 and 3 together make up the signature of a function.

To call the function you have to pass 2 integer arrays as its arguments.

The **mistake** : `value[100]` corresponds to an **INTEGER ENTRY** in the array and not the array itself.

To pass the array you should pass the array name as its argument, which your function expects.

Call the function like this: `knapsack(value, weight)`

*value* corresponds the *array value* and *weight* corresponds to the *array weight*

Also, passing `value[100]` corresponds to some garbage value that is not within the array bounds as you can only access elements ranging from `value[0]` to `value[99]` (0-based indexing).